# Bluetooth LE MIDI latency?

Tags: midi, latency

What is the typical added latency of using Apple's Bluetooth LE MIDI connection, versus using a (USB or Lightning) wired connection?

Comment: go ask on the website that sells the product for cryin out loud

Comment: It's a (MIDI standard?) protocol that's applicable to many interoperable music products from multiple manufacturers.

Comment: See [Latency issues with MIDI Over Bluetooth](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26379706/11654).

Answer (score 2):

- Apple USB MIDI (iOS/macOS) latency: approx 3.5ms
- Apple BLE MIDI macOS latency: approx 17 ms
- Apple BLE MIDI iOS latency: approx 22.5 ms

These values were measured with MIDI latency tests designed for this purpose.

Comment: What's your source for this?

Comment: I conducted the tests.

Answer (score 1):

This is a YMMV question - as the latency is going to vary based on your configuration. For instance, the version of your Bluetooth, the signal strength and even where you are in proximity to the LE MIDI connection. These are all variables that make subtle or sometimes dramatic differences in the latency you experience. So you can check on the average expected throughput with Apple, but by using a wired connection - USB also has different versions 2.0 to 4.0 are common if your computer supports it, and Lightning is also a different variable in speed. You need to test in your own environment to see what works best for you. You are only as fast as your weakest link.

Comment: Yes, there's always a worse case scenario, but I'll settle for a typical latency range, small home studio (controller next to Mac or synth), and not under a NORAD radio dome or other dramatic interference.  Usable, or annoyingly longer delays than MIDI cables?  Maybe from a musician's actual user experience.